# O-ring for high pressure air valve

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I have this drawing of an high pressure air valve and I want to build my own based on this design.
[image]
I have a question regarding the o-ring.
There is no groove on the drawing and located where it is, I think it will be destroyed by the sharp angle and will not work properly.
This is supposed to support up to 300 bar /4500 psi
For scale, o ring internal diameter is 6.5mm

Any idea what should I do here taking into account the small size and the high pressure?

Comment: Is the seal actually done with the piston in the hole ie a clase tolerance fit? Then the o ring may be to just stop chattering or bounce.

Comment: clearly the design shown won't work, there's not anything keeping the ring in place.  But that looks like a relief valve, not a shutoff valve.  Why would you want the valve to operate against a larger area?

Comment: 4500 psi valves  basically  have metal to metal seats.